# Detecting swipe and area of swipe

Tags: android, touch, swipe

In my Android app, I want to detect swipes in different directions.
I also want to know where the swipe started, went through, and ended so I can know which areas were swiped.

How would I go about setting this up?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean you're trying to detect it in your Android app?

Comment: I'm trying to write an app. One of the things it needs to do is recognize where in 4 quadrants a swipe is registered